# Searching Against Projected EF Core Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, projection, navigation-properties

Using EF Core 3.1, I'm trying to perform a search against a nullable navigation property (a.k.a. left join) after it has been projected to a different type.

For example:

```
var dtos = await query
    .Select(x => new RootEntityDto
    {
        // ...

        Nested = x.NestedId.HasValue
            ? new NestedEntityDto
            {
                // ...

                Description = x.Nested.Description
            }
            : null
    })
    .Where(x => x.Nested.Description.Contains("2"))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

The problem is, it gives me an error over the ternary that may conditionally result in null:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<RootEntity>
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: DbSet<NestedEntity>, 
        inner: f => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(f, "NestedId"), 
        outerKeySelector: o => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(o, "Id"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<RootEntity, NestedEntity>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(f => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(f.Inner, "Id") != null ? new NestedEntityDto{ 
        Description = f.Inner.Description, 
    }
     : null.Description.Contains("2"))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

If I try precisely the same thing before projecting the entity to a DTO, I have no problems:

```
var entities = await query
    .Where(x => x.Nested.Description.Contains("2"))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

I realize the simple solution is to perform the `Where` statement before the projection occurs, but that's not an option. The above examples are simplified in order to illustrate the intent. I'm also not interested in evaluating the query client-side just because I don't know a better alternative to the ternary.

Ideally, I'm just looking for the best practice for conditionally projecting a left join navigation property, such that I can still perform searches on it.

Edit: I decided to try AutoMapper 10.1.1 and received a similar error:

```
var dtos = await query
    .ProjectTo<RootEntityDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider, x => x.Nested)
    .Where(x => x.Nested.Description.Contains("2"))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<RootEntity>
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: DbSet<NestedEntity>, 
        inner: f => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(f, "NestedId"), 
        outerKeySelector: o => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(o, "Id"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<RootEntity, NestedEntity>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(f => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(f.Inner, "Id") == null ? null : new NestedEntityDto{ 
        Description = f.Inner.Description
    }
    .Description.Contains("2"))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research into what AutoMapper was doing and discovered a convention that works:

```
var dtos = await query
    .Select(x => new RootEntityDto
    {
        // ...

        Nested = x.Nested == null
            ? null
            : new NestedEntityDto
            {
                // ...

                Description = x.Nested.Description
            }
    })
    .Where(x => x.Nested.Description.Contains("2"))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Notice that I inverted the ternary *and* switched what would have been `!x.NestedId.HasValue` to `x.Nested == null`. But even with those changes, I still had to upgrade to EF Core 5.

Answer (score 2):

EF Core 3 completely changed how the queries were evaluated and not all query constructs are supported. I suspect trying to filter after the DTO projection is the underlying issue here. Could you test upgrading to EF Core 5 with this query and see if it still fails there as well as more query patterns are supported with 5.

Comment: Same error after upgrading Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer from 3.1.9 to 5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6.

Comment: Turns out that the combination of EF Core 5 and AutoMapper can handle this, but not either one by itself.